# dynamic Javascript to make a rainbow tiered list

Tags: javascript

So, I have a set of lists in lists like the following:

```
<ul>
 <li>
 Blah
  <li>
  Blah
  <ul>
    <li>
    Blah
    </li>
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  Blah
  </li>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I could always do:

```
ul li{Symbolbytextthingcolor?:red}
ul ul li{Symbolbytextthingcolor?:orange}
ul ul ul li{Symbolbytextthingcolor?:yellow}
```

but this is tedious and I'd rather do something like

```
colorList(["red","orange","yellow"...])
```

anyone have ideas on how to use dynamically use JavaScript to apply a rainbow tiered symbol system for my lists? Thanks.

Comment: What is so tedious about the CSS solution? It really is the better solution compared to a JavaScript-based solution. How deep are your `ul` tags nested?

Comment: is the list already there when the javascript applys the colors? or the javascript is suppose to build the list as well?